# Prove that $r^n/n!$ converges where $n\ge r$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The answer is in the title of the question.  I need to show it converges to 0 and $r>0$.  I am sorry if this is a bad question, I'm having trouble explaining it.  So essentially this Do the $\lim_{n\to inf}\frac{r^n}{n!}=0.$

Comment: comparison test?

Comment: Sorry I can't use that.  I would love to, but I think I need to use like the definition of convergence.  I can't use any test because technically we haven't learned them

Comment: I think there is a typo. What does $n\geq r$ have to do with anything? Aren't you proving something where $n\to \infty$?

Comment: notice that $r^n/n!=r/1 \times r/2 \times ... r/n$ ?

and yes matt I agree with you but we all know what he means. :)

Comment: As written the question makes no sense. Are $r$ and $n$ both varying? Is $n$ fixed and $r$ varies? We are computing the limit of the expression as what variable is tending to what value?

Comment: I believe I fixed it.  I am very sorry for not stating that.

Comment: Still makes no sense. You want to compute a limit, something of the form $\lim_{a\to b}f(a)$. What is $a$ in your case? What is $b$?

Comment: Do the $\lim_{n\to inf}\frac{r^n}{n!}=0.$

Comment: "Do the $lim=0$". Please put a modicum of effort on your phrasing of your homework. You already know it is $0$, what is left to "do"?

Comment: I need to prove it.  I don't know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asume that you want to prove:

$$\lim_n\displaystyle\frac{r^n}{n!}=0 $$

and $r>0$ is fixed.

Let $N$ be an integer number such that $N> r$. Then for $n>N$ the following holds:

$$\displaystyle\frac{r^n}{n!}=\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}\displaystyle\frac{r}{N}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{n}<\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}(\displaystyle\frac{r}{N})^{n-N}   $$

you have that $\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}$ is a constant and $\displaystyle\frac{r}{N}<1$. Try to conclude.

Comment: sorry, could you just help me with the conclusion a bit? is it because $\frac{r}{N}<1$, it is a geometric series, it converges?

Comment: Using the fact
$$\lim_n (\displaystyle\frac{r}{N})^n=0$$
you can bound
$$\displaystyle\frac{r^n}{n!}$$
as near as zero as you want. Because of the inequality above. 
Note: you don't have to think nothing about series. Only sucession.