# Prove that $r^n/n!$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to show that $r^n/n!$ converges where $n\ge r$. Which is basically showing $\lim_{n\to inf}\frac{r^n}{n!}=0.$. Yotas Trejos told I need to do this

Let $N$ be an integer number such that $N> r$. Then for $n>N$ the following holds:

$$\displaystyle\frac{r^n}{n!}=\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}\displaystyle\frac{r}{N}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{n}<\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}(\displaystyle\frac{r}{N})^{n-N}   $$

you have that $\displaystyle\frac{r}{1}\cdots\displaystyle\frac{r}{N-1}$ is a constant and $\displaystyle\frac{r}{N}<1$.

But I'm having trouble concluding it.  Is it just because it is a geometric sequence then after that?

Comment: Jack, the "work" you show is not yours (see duplicate question linked above, and the answer). You copied and pasted the answer of a user that spent time trying to help you. You need to attribute that work to the user who wrote it, or better yet, you should have linked the answer, and not simply refer to that user as "someone".

Comment: See [the answer to which I refer in comment above](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/763940/9003)

Comment: sorry about that. Didn't mean to be rude or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you've bounded $r^n\leq n!$ by $\frac{r}{N-1}\left(\frac{r}{N}\right)^{n-N}$, and that $N$ depends $only$ on $r$ which is fixed in this problem. Thus you have that:

$$\frac{r^n}{n!}\leq C \left(\frac{r}{N}\right)^n$$

where $C$ is a constant that depends only on $r$. Now, $0<r/N<1$, so really you're trying to show that $R:=r/N$ satisfies $R^n\rightarrow 0$. But this is hopefully something you know how to do already.